# How to get an object by the name in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a ridiculous object like this.

```
{
order: ["a1","a2","a3","a4"],  
posts: {
a1: {id: "a1",message: "This is a1"},
a4: {id: "a4",message: "This is a4"},
a3: {id: "a3",message: "This is a3"},
a2: {id: "a2",message: "This is a2"},
}
}
```

I need to get "message" value from "posts" object with the order that define in "order" array. I can foreach the "order" array, but how to know when I have "a1" string, I need to take "a1" object in "posts" object?

Thank you!

Comment: `const str = 'a1'; obj.posts[str]` ??? It's not clear what you're asking

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you have to do is map over the order array and return the object based on keys using brackets notation like

```js
const data = {
order: ["a1","a2","a3","a4"],  
posts: {
a1: {id: "a1",message: "This is a1"},
a4: {id: "a4",message: "This is a4"},
a3: {id: "a3",message: "This is a3"},
a2: {id: "a2",message: "This is a2"},
}
}

const res = data.order.map((id) => {
    return data.posts[id];
})

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope below code may help.

```js
const data = {
order: ["a1","a2","a3","a4"],  
posts: {
a1: {id: "a1",message: "This is a1"},
a4: {id: "a4",message: "This is a4"},
a3: {id: "a3",message: "This is a3"},
a2: {id: "a2",message: "This is a2"},
}
}

Object.entries(data.order).forEach(([key, val]) => {
    console.log(data.posts[val]);          
});
```

Comment: Why do you suggest to write `Object.entries(data.order).forEach(([key, val]) => {` instead of simply writing `data.order.forEach( val => {`? What is the reason for using `Object.entries` and destructing here?

Comment: 1) there was no specific reason for keeping `key`.
2) I used `Object.entries`, because it fits properly for the questioner expectation to access `posts` values in order by `order`.

Comment: I tried your idea with forEach order and get posts[value]. It can work too. I didn't know we can use posts[id] when posts is not an array.

Comment: For **2.** then you should definitily not use [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) because `[...]the Object.entries() method returns[...]in the same order as that provided by a for...in loop` and [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) `[...]for...in should not be used to iterate over an Array [...]There is no guarantee that for...in will return the indexes in any particular order.` so the order is not guaranteed for your code.